# FizzBuzz program never satisfies one of the conditions

Tags: python, if-statement, modulus, fizzbuzz

Write a Python program that displays a message as follows for a given number:

If it is a multiple of three, display "Zip"
If it is a multiple of five, display "Zap".
If it is a multiple of both three and five, display "Zoom".
If it does not satisfy any of the above given conditions, display "Invalid".

```py
def display(num):
    message="Zip, Zap, Zoom"

    if(num%3==0):
      print("Zip")
    elif(num%5==0):
      print("Zap")
    elif((num%3==0) and (num%5==0)):
      print("Zoom")
    else:
      print("Invalid Number")
    return message


message=display(15)
print(message)
```

I expect the output of 15 to be Zoom, but the actual output is Zip.

Answer (score 2):

you need to reorder your if...elif...else statement

If the condition for if is False, it checks the condition of the next elif block and so on, but if one of statements are true body of that statement is executed  and exit.

If all the conditions are False, body of else is executed.

```
def display(num):

    if((num%3==0) and (num%5==0)):
        message = "Zoom"
    elif(num%3==0):
        message = "Zip"
    elif(num%5==0):
        message = "Zap"
    else:
      print("Invalid Number")
    return message


message=display(3)
print(message)
```

Answer (score 1):

this is because 15 is multiple of 3 and satisfies first condition so the output is "Zip". you can fix it simply as follow:

```
if(num%3==0 and num%5!=0):
  print("Zip")
elif(num%5==0 and num%3!=0):
  print("Zap")
elif((num%3==0) and (num%5==0)):
  print("Zoom")
else:
  print("Invalid Number")
return message
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative: [Takes value from the user. Hope it helps!]

```
num=int(input("Enter the value : "))

if(num % 5 == 0):
    if(num % 3 == 0):
        print("Zoom")
    else:
         print("Zap") 
elif(num % 3 == 0):
     print("Zip")
else:
     print("invalid")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution in Java**

> Implement a program that displays a message for a given number based on the below conditions.
> If the number is a multiple of 3, display "Zip".
> If the number is a multiple of 5, display "Zap".
> If the number is a multiple of both 3 and 5, display "Zoom",
> For all other cases, display "Invalid".

```
class ZipZapZoom 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // Implement your code here 
        int num = 10;
        if(num % 3==0 & num %5 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Zoom");
            
        }
        else if(num % 5 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Zap");
        }
        else if(num % 3==0)
        {
            System.out.println("Zip");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def display(num):
    message=""

    if(num%3==0):
      print("Zip")
    elif(num%5==0):
      print("Zap")
    elif((num%3==0) and (num%5==0)):
      print("Zoom")
    else:
      print("Invalid Number")
    return message

#Provide different values for num and test your program
message=display(12)
print(message)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].